# Background NFC Tag reading on iOS - No usable data found

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

I'm trying to implement background NFC tag reading for an iOS app. The NFC tag I am using has specific requirements as to the format that must be written - specifically, only the second record can be a URI, and it must be 56 characters long.

I've constructed and written the following NDEF message:

```swift
        let message = NFCNDEFMessage(records: [
            NFCNDEFPayload(
                format: .nfcExternal,
                type: "-- omitted --".data(using: .utf8)!,
                identifier: "".data(using: .utf8)!,
                payload: "-- omitted --".data(using: .utf8)!
            ),
            NFCNDEFPayload(
                format: .nfcWellKnown,
                type: "U".data(using: .utf8)!,
                identifier: "".data(using: .utf8)!,
                payload: "https://apple.com?                                      ".data(using: .utf8)!
            ),
            NFCNDEFPayload(
                format: .nfcWellKnown,
                type: "T".data(using: .utf8)!,
                identifier: "".data(using: .utf8)!,
                payload: "-- omitted --".data(using: .utf8)!
            )
        ])
```

Now when I touch an iOS device to the phone, I get a prompt saying (original in parens, assumed English translation first):

> NFC-TAG DETECTED (NFC-TAG GEDETECTEERD)
>
> No usable data found (Green bruikbare gegevens gevonden)

I have tried replacing the whitespace with `?_______...` or with Universal Links but I always get the same response. When I try reading other NFC tags that I have not written to I don't get the prompt, so I know the new message is activating background reading, but I can't figure out why it can't be read.

My only guess is that iOS is not decoding the `.utf8` byte array, but I don't know how else to store/encode a message to an NFC tag

Answer (score 0):

I replaced:

```swift
NFCNDEFPayload(
   format: .nfcWellKnown,
   type: "U".data(using: .utf8)!,
   identifier: "".data(using: .utf8)!,
   payload: "https://apple.com?                                      ".data(using: .utf8)!
),
```

with:

```swift
NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload(string: "https://apple.com?_____________________________________________")!
```

I don't know why

1. I needed a longer string (63 characters)
2. Why that string was still only 56 bytes
3. What is different in the constructor
4. Why I did in fact need the underscores, as whitespace did not register as a background tag

Perhaps someone else can yet explain this solution. However, it works!

Comment: Hopefully my answer will answer some of these questions i.e. why it is shorter (because the NDEF URI scheme is trying to be efficient and encodes common URI prefixes in to a single byte e.g. 8 bytes of `https://` to a 1 byte code)

Answer (score 0):

So https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading says

> Note
> Background tag reading doesn’t support custom URL schemes. Use
> universal links instead.

With

```
NFCNDEFPayload(
   format: .nfcWellKnown,
   type: "U".data(using: .utf8)!,
   identifier: "".data(using: .utf8)!,
   payload: "https://apple.com?                                      ".data(using: .utf8)!
),
```

I don't think you are using one of the supported URL schema from the linked docs, you are using a "Custom URL scheme" that it says it does not support.

Using the help function `NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload` this probably decodes your string in to a supported URL scheme.

The docs are not clear and references the NDEF spec for URI's which is at https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf

So my guess is that to do the more manual create of the `NFCNDEFPayload` you need to format it correctly as

```
NFCNDEFPayload(
   format: .nfcWellKnown,
   type: "U".data(using: .utf8)!,
   identifier: "4".data(using: .utf8)!,
   payload: "apple.com?".data(using: .utf8)!
),
```

As `4` is the decimal code for the `https://` prefix

Comment: From the same apple developer docs: `Background tag reading supports the following URL schemes: [ http/https ... ]`. The `4` as the decimal code for the `https://` is interesting though! thanks